# Speeding up django .exists()

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-queryset

I have a query `TranslationStep.objects.filter(step_id=pk)`. I need to check if object is exist or not and if so, return object (or several objects). I have read that `.exists()` is more fastest way to do it, but I should make 2 requests.

```
if TranslationStep.objects.filter(step_id=pk).exists():
 return TranslationStep.objects.filter(step_id=pk)
else:
 return None
```

How can I optimise it?

Comment: Why not just return TranslationStep.objects.filter(step_id=pk), and forget about the check? Now the caller of your function has to make a check to see if they got a queryset or None in return.

Comment: Django try/except [get-object-or-404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do this at all. `filter()` will return an empty queryset if there is no match, which is False in a boolean context.